# Will the same heat sink and fan work?

Tags: cpu, heatsink, amd-phenom, cpu-cooler

My friend has a Compaq Presario SR5703WM Desktop PC
[Product Page](http://h10025.www1.hp.com/ewfrf/wc/product?product=3875750&lc=en&cc=us&dlc=en&lang=en&tmp_track_link=ot_we/prodlink/en_us/3875750/loc:0&cc=us)

He Wanted to upgrade and was gonna get another faster by 600 mhz sempron, after research i told him to get a dual core or quadcore , but his budget was limited.

So we found a guy on craiglist and got an AMD Phenom X4, which was lucky as it happened the same day he decided to upgrade.

```
2.3 Ghz. X4.
Socket AM2, and Socket AM2+.
Agena Core.
95 Watt.
```

thing is the guy hasnt provided a heatsink and fan... will the same heatsink and fan work...

for the time being we aint gonna overclock, but in future might (if i do it, he is a big noob and wont touch)

Comment: On the same motherboard or a different one?

Comment: It's impossible to tell, it depends on clearance issues inside the case if the heatsink is a physically different size.  In terms of socket compatibility, if they both work with AM2, it will fit.  We need a link to the AMD spec page for the processor, or at minimum the processor model - or we can't help you.  The Phenom X4 is Socket AM3, **not** Socket AM2.

Comment: same motherboard, that motherboard supports am3 processors
http://www.cpu-upgrade.com/mb-ASUS/M2N68-LA_(Narra3-GL8E).html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Same motherboard, roughly mini ATX or ATX sized case.. I think the same heatsink will work, as long as the processor does. If it was a SFF box, clearance would be an issue, but in this case, not so much

Comment: okat thanks ... i dont get it why are people downvoting this !!!

Comment: Well, grammar (mad case use) and somewhat of a lack of information i suppose. I personally assumed whatever processor you bought will work with your motherboard and focused on the heatsink

Answer (score 1):

The same heatsink and fan will "work" (i.e. physically fit), but your friend runs the risk of an overheated CPU.

The original CPU is a Sempron LE-1250, which has a 45 watt TDP rating.  Its original heatsink & fan is probably good for dissipating 65 watts.

The replacement CPU is specified by you as 95 watts TDP.  That could be 50% more heat that needs to be dissipated than the heatsink is designed for.  Either get a bigger heatsink, or be prepared to run the original fan at higher RPM to increase air flow.

FYI the old stock AM2 heatsinks IMO were not that good in dispersing the heated air.  The air flow through the heatsink exhausts in only two directions.  The newer AM3 stock heatsinks tend to have more exposed surface area (for better convection), and exhaust the heated air in four directions (essentially 360 degrees around the CPU).  This reduces the chances for dead zones of hot air within the computer case.